# Sockets - Reading and writing

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have created a server and client in C using TCP.
Everything works with this simple read and write method (same used for server and client).

*buf* is global variable in server and client.

**Good read()**

```
void read_from(int socket) {
    int readlen;
    if ((readlen = read(socket, buf, sizeof buf - 1)) < 0) {
        perror("read");
    }
    buf[readlen - 1] = '\0';
}
```

**Good write()**

```
void write_to(int socket) {
    if (write(socket, buf, sizeof buf - 1) < 0) {
        perror("write");
    }
}
```

I want to ensure everything is written, but I can't get it to work.
Using the same read method, this fails:

**Bad write()**

```
void write_to(int socket) {
    int buflen = strlen(buf);
    int written, offset = 0;

    while (offset <= buflen) {
        if ((written = write(socket, buf + offset, buflen - offset + 1)) < 0) {
            perror("write");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", written);
        offset += written;
    }
}
```

The output for *fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", written);* is correct, so the bad write() seems to write all the same bytes, but the receiver only reads a random half of the lines I send.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You are using a streaming socket, so you can't assume that `read` reads all the information sent by `write` at once. You need to have a message marker so you know when you've received a single `write_to` message.

Comment: Repeat after me: *TCP is a **stream** protocol, not a **message** protocol*.

Comment: I'd think there would be canonical question/answer for these type of questions, but I can't find it.